# hikari oracle connection Failing (spring boot)

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am trying to connect my oracle database using Hikari,
but for some reason on the line `HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(dbConfig);`
It is throwing me error that states

```
2020-10-29 00:06:51.496 [restartedMain] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(80) - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-10-29 00:06:52.608 [restartedMain] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(593) - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
```

```
 HikariConfig dbConfig = new HikariConfig();
        dbConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521/tabs1");
        dbConfig.setUsername("usernmae");
        dbConfig.setPassword("password");
        dbConfig.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dbConfig.setMinimumIdle(1);
        dbConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(3);
        dbConfig.setAutoCommit(false);
        log.info("Configs are :" +dbConfig);
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(dbConfig);
```

I have done a lot of research on it but unable to find the exact problem for the solution.

Comment: ORA-12514 SERVICE_NAME = tabs1 . Your database has not exposed this name to the database listener. db-node: sudo ss -tulpn | grep tns ; lsnrctl status | grep 'tabs1'. A database can register multiple service names for the exact same database. A service has certain properties. retres,timeout,failover...

Comment: @BjarteBrandt  actually I can connect same database from another server. I  Re routed the IP and use that server's IP (i can telnet that server's IP from this one )  but unable to connect database.
Is it possible it is failing on one server and connecting on other or database has not exposed "Tabs1" to one server but not other.

Comment: The listener process running on the dbnode exposes services. All clients connecting to the dbnode listener will "see" the services exposed (unless advanced setup with cman) on port 1521. If it works from another client-node and not this one, you establish connections to different ip's. (you have multiple listeners)

Answer (score 0):

Please use one of the following

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID
```

or

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOST:PORT/SERVICE
```

As far as I can see you miss the first two Backslash and end up in a Connect try to use a SID while Service Name not recognized.